# How do I modify the Site Collection in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint

When I try to open a form published from InfoPath I now get this error:

```
"The following location is not accessible, because it is in a different site collection: 

https//portal/sites/forms/Daily%20Activity/Forms/template.xsn?SaveLocation=https//portal.alamedacountyfire.org/sites/forms/Daily%20Activity/&Source=https//portal.alamedacountyfire.org/sites/forms/Daily%2520Activity/Forms/AllItems.aspx&ClientInstalled=false&OpenIn=Browser&NoRedirect=true&XsnLocation=https//PORTAL/sites/forms/Daily%20Activity/Forms/template.xsn."


Correlation ID:12c0ab9c-caff-80a8-f1b4-64d81dcfa6ea
```

Answer (score 0):

**Following are some options that you can try:**

1) Save the form template (.xsn) as the source files in the publish options. Look at the manifest file in notepad and see if you can find a reference to the incorrect location. If so, correct it and Republish the form.

2) Clear the InfoPath cache on that machine. Start->Run "infopath /cache clearall"

3) See if the site collection has a managed path, if so, give the proper url while publishing. The XSN might be getting deployed on the root site and throws error since the intended list does'nt exist.

Comment: How do I check #3? So far no luck on the problem. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: You can verify #3 by checking if the Site collection to which the form is getting published is correct or not. 

For example, your root site collection is http://demosite and the form is published in this site collection. 

Now, if you have another site collection within the managed path (sites), say http://demosite/sites/NewSite, and you try to open the form, you will get an error similar to one that you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked for me.  Got the answer from [another post](http://www.faqssys.info/infopath-error-the-following-location-is-not-accessible-because-it-is-in-a-different-site-collection-except-it-isnt/).

"I had a similar problem and found it was due to the request management service routing from my web application host header to the server name. 
There was a routing rule in my request management settings. I just disabled routing and the problem went away. I used the following powershell to disable it. "

```
$w = Get-SPWebApplication "http://webapphostname"
$r = $w | Get-SPRequestManagementSettings
$r.RoutingEnabled = $false
$r.Update()
```

You may want to configure it rather than disable it. Here’s a good resource to get you started:

http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2013rm1.aspx